# PowerShell copy only files with numbers in their name

Tags: powershell, filesystems, script, copy

I want to copy files from a path to a destination. The files i want to copy only contain numbers in their name and always have a specific structure like "xxxx_xxxxxx.upd". Sadly there are others .upd files in the directory, so i cant copy *.upd.

This is what i did:

```
Copy-Item -Path S:\Backup\Updates\*.upd -Destination S:\Running\Main
```

Now i get all .upd files but i only want those which contain no characters in their name like 2021_030252.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: so ... where is your code? what have you tried? what did not work as expected?

Comment: Now i get all upd files but i want only those which only contain numbers in their name and no characters.

Comment: please, add all the needed info to your Question. putting stuff in the comments makes it difficult to find. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's one way to get those files. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- sets the constants
- grabs all the files from the source that match the filter
  i have no `*.upd` files, so i used `*.log` files. [*grin*]
- uses the `W-O` cmdlet to filter OUT any file that does not match the regex pattern
  that pattern requires the `.BaseName` contain ONLY the digits 0-9 and the underscore.
- saves the files to `$FileList`
- shows that list on the screen

the code ...

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$Filter = '*.log'

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -File -Filter $Filter |
    Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '^[0-9_]+$'}

$FileList
```

the output ...

```
    Directory: C:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2021-03-01   5:32 PM              0 12345_9604.log
-a----        2021-02-26   6:33 PM              0 1_560.log
```

note that my temp dir has `*.log` files with letter/number combos ... and those were excluded as desired.